# db queries inside loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a question regarding db queries inside of a foreach loop. Im making a guestbook for users on a site. i store "user_id", "owner_id" "message" in db table "guestbook". And loop through them to display the posts on the page. But in that loop i get the "username" in the "users" table where id = user_id by calling a whois_model directly.

```
<?php foreach ($records as $record) : ?>
From: <?=anchor('profile/view/' . $record->user_id . '', $this->whois_model->_whois($record->user_id)); ?>

<p><?=$record->message; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is it better to store the username in the guestbook table directly, or is there a better approach to avoid running multiple queries?

Thanks in advance

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't denormalize your data unless you have a good reason to. Not only you are wasting space, but if you also have a username column in your `records` table, what happens when a user changes their name?

The better way to do this is to have your model or your controller retrieve the username automatically whenever you plan to use it. This can be done using a join, eg:

```
$this->db->select('username, message');
$this->db->from('guestbook');
$this->db->join('users', 'guestbook.user_id = users.user_id');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Remember that the view should only be used to display information; you shouldn't have to fetch anything from the database (eg: via another model) in the view.

Comment: Oh ofcourse! A JOIN! Dont know why i didnt think of that :/ Thanks for the help all. You were first so voted yours as the sollution. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to store the username in a separate table, you can use a JOIN to get the actual username in the same query without having to run multiple.

For example:

```
SELECT `messages`.`user_id`, `messages`.`owner_id`, `messages`.`message`, `users`.`username` FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN `users` ON (messages.user_id = users.id)
WHERE (clause)
ORDER BY (clause)
```

See [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store the username in the guestbook table. Instead, when you do your query for guestbook entries, join the user table (whatever table is backing your whois model) on user_id so that you get back all of the information in the guestbook and the username in a single query. Something like this in your query to retrieve records:

```
 ...
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('guestbook');
 $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = guestbook.user_id');
 ...
```